# MySQL command to substract two values from two different tables using MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
TABLE NAME::NEWSALES
--------------------------------------------                                                          
NID |BRAND  | QUANTITY |   PRICE  |  TOTAL |
---------------------------------------------
1  | D&G    |   50     |  2250.0  | 112500 |        
2  | GUCCI  |   40     |  2150.5  |  86020 |
---------------------------------------------
```

TABLE::SOLDOUT

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
SID |BRAND|   SOLD     |  PRICE |   TOTAL | REMAINING QUANTITY |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
10  | D&G   | 20     |   900  |   180000 |     ?               |
11  | GUCCI |  10    |   5375 |    53750 |     ?               |
 -----------------------------------------------------
```

//I need to subtract QUANTITY-SOLD=REMAINING QUANTITY
// example :: If we consider 'quantity' as 50 from NEWSALES table AND 'sold' as 20 from SOLDOUT table
 then it should give '50-20=30'(REMAINING QUANTITY)

Comment: Do all these rows apply to the same item? I.e., are your trying to get 50+40-20=70?

Comment: what's the logic behind finding remaining?

Comment: It must be like Remaining=Quantity(NEWSALES)-Sold(SOLDOUT)

Comment: How do the rows of `NEWSALES` relate to the rows of `SOLDOUT`?

Comment: they aren't related to each other NEWSALES is related to another table named SUPPLIER

Comment: atleast somebody provide me the syntax to substract

Comment: why IDs don't match? e.g. GUCCI has NID 2 and SID 11

Comment: The syntax to subtract is `-`.  Your question is quite unclear on *what* should be subtracted.  Please edit your question and include the results that you want for the sample data.

Comment: ok i get it the tables need to hav sum sort of relation so that further operations can be performed !!!